Does the Kardashev Scale have any practical application?
As the question states: are there any practical applications of the Kardashev Scale?

No. But this is not a physics question.

Not quite the answer you are looking for, but it's a really effective set of talking points for people.  The conerns of a class II civilization are fascinating, and completely unlike our concerns.

@JonCuster I did go back and forth on that point. I settled on the fact that Kardashev was a physicist, and if the scale does have a practical application, it may fall within the realms of physics. Do you have a suggestion for a more appropriate place for this.

According to this article, one "practical" application of the Kardashev Scale would be that it provides an indication of where in the universe one should focus efforts to detect possible advanced extraterrestrial civilizations (type II and III civilizations as referred to in this scale).
That is, such civilizations are alleged to be advanced enough that the creation of structures like the "Dyson Sphere" would be within their capabilities. But such a structure should cause the emission of radiation in a way that is unusual, thus making it stand out.
From the link:

Dyson-style energy collectors around a distant star would absorb and re-radiate energy from the star. The wavelengths of such re-radiated energy may be atypical for the star's spectral type, due to the presence of heavy elements not naturally occurring within the star. If the percentage of such atypical wavelengths were to be significant, an alien megastructure could be detected at interstellar distances. This could indicate the presence of what has been called a Type II Kardashev civilization.

Apart from this, there does not appear to be anything else of "practical" use. One may debate if this is practical, as speculating how an advanced civilization would harness energy is not scientific enquiry and borderlines on imagination.
Nevertheless, it is an interesting topic.
